# Haskell: ambiguous type variable in Storable when using sizeOf

Tags: haskell

Compilation of

```
byte_list_to_storable :: Storable a => [CUChar] -> MaybeT IO a    
byte_list_to_storable byte_list = do

  let
    size_of_storable = sizeOf (undefined :: a)

  when (length byte_list /= size_of_storable) mzero

  liftIO . alloca $ \pointer -> do
    forM (zip [0 .. size_of_storable - 1] byte_list)
      (\(index, byte) -> pokeByteOff pointer index byte)
    peek pointer
```

fails with

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (Storable a0) arising from a use of `sizeOf'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: sizeOf (undefined :: a)
In an equation for `size_of_storable':
    size_of_storable = sizeOf (undefined :: a)
In the expression:
  do { let size_of_storable = sizeOf (undefined :: a);
       when (length byte_list /= size_of_storable) mzero;
       liftIO . alloca $ \ pointer -> do { ... } }
```

despite explicit type annotation. It can be fixed with dummy argument:

```
byte_list_to_storable :: Storable a => a -> [CUChar] -> MaybeT IO a    
byte_list_to_storable dummy byte_list = do

  let
    size_of_storable = sizeOf dummy
```

But then `byte_list_to_storable` would have to be called as `byte_list_to_storable undefined ...` all the time. Is there any way to resolve ambiguity without dummy argument?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? And where do you expect the type of `a` to be deduced?

Comment: @Code-Guru I'm composing a storable value from a list of bytes. The list should have right length, and that's why I need to get the size of the type of the value I'm building by using `sizeOf`. Type of `a` is specified where `byte_list_to_storable` is called, e.g. `value :: FunPtr (IO ()) <- byte_list_to_storable bytes`.

Comment: Is the `undefined` part just stubbing something that is as yet to be completed?

Comment: @Code-Guru No, it's not stubbing. We have to give `sizeOf` a value even though it's not to inspect it in any way. So, when we don't have any value, we use `undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell type variables, like your `a`, by default *live only in one particular type signature*. When you write `sizeOf (undefined :: a)` further down, in the function definition, GHC does not associate this `a` in any way with the one in `MaybeT IO a`, but interprets it as a completely new, and unconstrained, type variable.

The way to change this is to turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

byteListToStorable :: forall a . Storable a => [CUChar] -> MaybeT IO a    
byteListToStorable bytelist = do
     let sizeOfStorable = sizeOf (undefined :: a)
     ...
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks! Actually, I had `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled, so it seems the answer is just adding `forall a .`. You said that type variables in any signature by default refer only to that particular signature, so adding `forall a .` makes type variables in the type signature of the function refer to its definition too. Is that how it works?

Comment: @myrix Yes, that is correct. The extension just enables the possibility of adding forall a b c ... for each type variable that you want to be scoped over the function body.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation @Sarah!